# Indexing-Loop of PaymentMethods in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Recently I encountered a strange problem when indexing payment methods in Shopware: it results in an endless loop of PaymentMethodIndexingMessages in the queue. After each handling of one message a new one is created with the same contents.

Currently on Shopware 6.5.6.1, but I also saw this in 6.4.x.
It seems like after the PaymentIndexer calls `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\DataAbstractionLayer\PaymentDistinguishableNameGenerator::generateDistinguishablePaymentNames` a new message is pushed into the queue. I suspect this happens because of the upsert of the payment methods in this method.

Has anyone an idea what could be the cause and how to stop the loop?

Comment: Are you using payment methods from external plugins?

Comment: Yes there are multiple payment plugins in use

Comment: I think I found a solution with what is described here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-data-indexer.html#use-dal-functionalities-in-the-indexer will report back, if it worked

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: during the payment-indexing there is currently an upsert using the DAL which triggers a new IndexingMessage.
Using the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-data-indexer.html#use-dal-functionalities-in-the-indexer) I found a solution in disabling the indexing in the context for this upsert-call.

The documentation is outdated in the way, the indexing has to be disabled. It should be using states instead of a context-extension:

```php
$context->addState(EntityIndexerRegistry::DISABLE_INDEXING);
```

Comment: Made a PR to Shopware to fix this behaviour: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/pull/3431